# Ubuntu clipboard manager that pastes from popup without Ctrl+V?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, clipboard

I've just discovered Glipper. Is it possible to have it paste the entry from pop-up as soon as I hit enter?

That is, get rid of the last step in the following sentence:

- Ctrl+Alt+C
- Navigate popup with arrows
- Enter
- Ctrl+V

I also evaluated Parcellite and it does not seem to support it either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middle click in your mouse to paste the selected text.